# Exception when checking if user is logged out

Tags: c#, skype

I'm getting an exception when checking if a user is logged out.

Code snippet:

```
if(skype.CurrentUserStatus == TUserStatus.cusLoggedOut)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bitte melde dich in Skype an.", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
}
```

But if i'm logged out and try to debug it, i get a exception.

> Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" ist in    alphasn0w.exe aufgetreten.
>
> Zusätzliche Informationen: Not attached.

Translation:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in alphasn0w.exe.
>
> Additional information: Not attached.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which line causes the Exception?

Comment: This SO thread might offer some insights on how to debug COM Exceptions. This could be as simple as a user rights issue that's resolved by running VS as admin.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281425/how-to-avoid-a-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception

Comment: @MikeG the first line of the code snippet.

Comment: Is there an alternative, to check if the user is logged out?

Comment: What's the type of the exception thrown at line 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you're not attached to Skype.

You'll want to do:

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.attach(7, true);
```

The "true" means it'll wait until the user has clicked "Allow", then continue with your code.