# Server Authentication in Windows Run Time Component for background agent

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8.1, gmail-api, background-agents

I am working on a windows phone project that pulls data from gmail server using gmail api and downloads all the attachments with the specific format, everything works (server authentication, receiving data, ... ) well when I have all the code in the same project. 
I added a Windows Runtime component project to the solution and moved the code that handles server authentication and returns a GmailService to the runtime component project, so I could call it from a background agent scheduler project for push notifications as well as in the main project.
I get this error every time I try to call the Server in the main project :

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

```
 public static async Task<GmailService> Instantiate()
    {
        if (service == null)
            await AuthenticateAsync();
        return service;
    }

    private static async Task AuthenticateAsync()
    {
          // the code that creates the service if it doesn't exist
     }
```

I added the reference to both scheduler and main project, and build are done successfully .

Answer (score 0):

This thread (below link) suggests both running VS as administrator, and also how to debug the COMException to get a better idea of what is causing it. Sounds like a problem with target architecture of the new VS project you created. Excerpt below;

"You could try breaking when the exception is thrown. Go to Debug > Exceptions... and use the Find... option to locate System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Tick the option to break when it's thrown and then debug your application."

[How to avoid a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281425/how-to-avoid-a-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception)